# librosa melspectrogram y-axis scale wrong?

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing, librosa, mel

I'm trying to figure out why Mel scale spectrogram seems to have the wrong frequency scale. I generate a 4096Hz tone and plot it using librosa's display library, and the tone does not align with the known frequency? I'm obviously doing something wrong, can someone help? Thanks!

```
import numpy as np
import librosa.display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sr = 44100
t = np.linspace(0, 1, sr)
y = 0.1 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * 4096 * t)

M = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=y, sr=sr)
M_db = librosa.power_to_db(M, ref=np.max)
librosa.display.specshow(M_db, y_axis='mel', x_axis='time')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you compute the mel spectrogram using `librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=y, sr=sr)` you implicitly create a mel filter using the parameters `fmin=0` and `fmax=sr/2` (see [docs here](https://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.filters.mel.html#librosa.filters.mel)). To correctly plot the spectrogram, `librosa.display.specshow` needs to know how it was created, i.e. what sample rate `sr` was used (to get the time axis right) and what frequency range was used to get the frequency axis right. While `librosa.feature.melspectrogram` defaults to `0 - sr/2`, `librosa.display.specshow` unfortunately defaults to `0 - 11050` (see [here](https://github.com/librosa/librosa/blob/a53fa56bdb6695a994008d5b6ccd0100870a6036/librosa/display.py#L1124)). This describes librosa 0.8—I could imagine this changes in the future.

To get this to work correctly, explicitly add `fmax` parameters. To also get the time axis right, add the `sr` parameter to `librosa.display.specshow`:

```
import numpy as np
import librosa.display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sr = 44100
t = np.linspace(0, 1, sr)
y = 0.1 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * 4096 * t)

M = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=y, sr=sr, fmax=sr/2)
M_db = librosa.power_to_db(M, ref=np.max)
librosa.display.specshow(M_db, sr=sr, y_axis='mel', x_axis='time', fmax=sr/2)
plt.show()
```

[image: correct mel spectrogram plot]